# Проверку, лежит ли точка внутри окружности

Tags: python

Задана окружность (x-a)2 + (y-b)2 = R2 и точки Р(р1, р2), F(f1, f1), L(l1,l2). Выяснить и вывести на экран, сколько точек лежит внутри окружности. Проверку, лежит ли точка внутри окружности, оформить в виде процедуры.

```
  def task(a,b,r,c):
            return len(list(filter(lambda x : (x[0]-a)**2+(x[1]-b)**2 < r**2, c )))
            
        print(task(int(input('Введите точку a: ')),
    int(input('Введите точку b: ')),
    int(input('Введите радиус: ')),
    [[int(i) for i in input('Введите точки р1, р2: ').split()],
    [int(i) for i in input('Введите точки f1, f2: ').split()],
    [int(i) for i in input('Введите точки l1,l2: ').split()]]))
```

1)Правильно ли?

2)Как написать проверку, лежит ли точка внутри окружности, в виде процедуры

Comment: print лопнет от такого!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Правильно ли?

Результат - правильный. Попытка пропихать всё в одну строчку - не правильная :)

> Как написать проверку в виде процедуры

Процедурой называют программу / функцию, которая последовательно выполняет какие-то инструкции. Иногда это слово используют как синоним для "функции". В контексте задачи, имеется в виду функция, которая получит координаты точки, центра окружности и выдаст True / False.

```
def int_input(msg = ''):
    x = input(msg).strip().split()

    return int(x) if len(x) <= 1 else map(int, x)

###
cx, cy, r = int_input('Введите коор-ты центра окружности и радиус (через пробелы): ')
# ↖________________________   (числа сразу сохраняются в виде значений параметров
#                          ↓          по умолчанию, в момент создания функции)
def includes(px, py, cx = cx, cy = cy, r = r):
    return (px - cx) ** 2 + (py - cy) ** 2 < r ** 2

###
included_points = 0

for p in ('P', 'F', 'L'):
    px, py = int_input(f'Введите коор-ты точки {p}: ')   # Справка: «f-string»
    included_points += includes(px, py)

print(included_points)
```

* `cx = cx` — названия могут отличаться, они совпали случайно)

** `+= includes(px, py)` в мат-операциях `True → 1`, `False → 0`